# MOSS 2007: Unsafe webparts, file not found, and more fun

Tags: 2007, web-part, safe-controls

One day lately our dev server started acting very strangely. No configuration settings were changed the previous day. Nothing was deployed to the site either.

Symptoms: all custom web parts cannot be imported because they aren't registered as safe. They are registered in the web.config as safe and normally are deployed to the IIS bin folder. They've since been installed to the GAC as well and are still deemed unsafe.

Application pages that use these web parts give a SharePoint version (YSOD) of "File not found".

I've removed all of the web parts from the home page with content=1 (which is a site page) and it loads but I can't add them back because they're unsafe. I can also access site settings if I type in the URL directly.

I've made sure that no service accounts were locked out and rebuilt and redeployed the web parts. I saw mention of the SSP sometimes causing this (??) so I created a new web app and tried to create a new SSP to experiment. It failed during provisioning with an error which escapes me ATM (something about not being able to access the pipe). Named pipes are enabled so I'm not sure if any of this SSP creation problem is related or separate.

Any tips or info is appreciated. I'm completely stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first, remove the webpart totally from the solution managment in central admin by retracting the wsp and then remove(delete) from solution explorer.

Now go add it again using stsadm or wspbuilder as i prefer as it does the safecontrols for you.

If using stsadm check that its registered in the web.config make sure its correct and the same as the dll in the gac

do an iisreset.

make sure its deployed to the webapp in solution explorer

add it to the gallery, check overwrite existing if it already exists

add the webpart to the page :)

extra notes are:

check your manifest files, it will contain the safecontrols where its directing it to and the name of the assembly.

if you use wspbuilder than it will build it for you, pritty much does everything for you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately the solution does not use WSPBuilder (I inherited this piece of junk). It is installed on the system though. Is it possible to implement WSPBuilder into an existing solution without too much effort? I've only ever used it from the get-go. If so I will Google it as to not waste your time. Thanks for the response!

Comment: i presume you have the projects? if so, open then up in visula studios and right click the project in solution explorer, if you have wspbuilder installed then you can see it in the first menu. Build the wsp and then deploy and then add the webpart to the gallery then to the page :)

Comment: Ali, I'm making progress! The web part now loads but I'm getting an error saying index is out of range. Event Viewer shows that access to the SharePoint_Config database is not available. I'm working with the DBA to correct this. WSPBuilder got me this far. I hope that I'm on the right track. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: thats fine, maybe you have some settings missing on the webpart properties? like db connection settings?, edit the page and then edit the webpart to make sure the settings are correct! to me it sounds like a piece of code needed somthing from the sharepoint_config table and returned 0 but in a loop its gone over that value and hence produced that error, there should be a check to make sure that it returns a value without breaking the webpart informing that there is no values and why :) but it looks like you are very much on the right track :)